# Rewrite fsockopen to curl

Tags: php, curl

I have a code which returns server response, but it's using `fscokopen` function which is not available on the server I'm using on this project.

How to rewrite this to CURL or similar alternative?

```
$server = 'whois.afilias.net';
$fp = @fsockopen($server, 43,$errno, $errstr, $this->m_connectiontimeout);
        if( $fp ){
            @fputs($fp, $domain."\r\n");
            @socket_set_timeout($fp, $this->m_sockettimeout);
            while( !@feof($fp) ){
                $data .= @fread($fp, 4096);
            }
            @fclose($fp);

            return $data;
        }else{
            return "\nError - could not open a connection to $server\n\n";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

See for [more options of curl](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).